# Como utilizar classe RealmObject

Tags: java, android

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Android e ao tentar utilizar a classe **RealmObject** a mesma não é reconhecida, mesmo importando o pacote **io.realm.RealmObject**.

Não está mais disponível esta classe?

Comment: Já instalaste o plugin? Isso não vem por defeito no Android.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção. Consegui resolver da forma que respondi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver este problema é necessário colocar a biblioteca no **build.gradle**.

classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"

No meu caso ficou dessa maneira:

```
dependencies {
      classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"    
}
```

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar sua resposta como correta :D

Comment: Feito, obrigado